# Use dynamic og tag for sharing post in sites.com

Tags: force.com-sites, facebook

we have a blog page in our client site.com.
On that blog page theres a bunch of meta tag - a.k.a og tags - which facebook, gplus, twitter and linkedIn uses to build the post preview.
The problem is that our current code doesn't load completely.

we have the following:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://xxxx/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!imagemBanner}?asPdf=false&amp;operationContext=CHATTER" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{!conexao.Chamada__c}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://xxxx/xxxx?post={!conexao.URL__c}" />
 <meta property="og:title" content="{!conexao.Titulo__c}" />
```

But on facebook it does not show the binded fields:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="https://xxxxx/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/?asPdf=false&amp;#38;operationContext=CHATTER" property="og:image">
<meta content="" property="og:description">
<meta content="https://xxxxx/xxxx?post=" property="og:url">
<meta content="" property="og:title">
```

The binded fields are not loaded.
How can this be achieved?